# Phinx init does not work

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration, phinx

I would like to install Phinx db migrations in my project, but [documentation](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/install.html) commands do not work. At first it is impossible to run 

`php vendor/bin/phinx init`

because phinx is not php commant. Ok so I went to bin directory and run phinx.bat but this generated the yaml config file to bin folder not to the root dir as they says in documentation, but to the bin directory. What should I do to get correct installation?

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is I am on Windows and I need to write Windows separator so this command works: `vendor\bin\phinx init`